# How to auto scroll to PropID worked listed in Table using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I auto-scroll view to specific PropID post I complete working on PropID?

I am using ASP.Net MVC, and bootstrap table.

I did write a code but it is not working.

```
@if(ViewBag.PropID != null)
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Handler for .ready() called.
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('@ViewBag.PropID').offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        });
    </script>
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the *exact* value of `ViewBag.PropID`?   It's likely you need `scrollTop: $('#' +'@ViewBag.PropID').offset().top`  (ie add the `'#'`, separated to ensure the `@` doesn't get mixed (it shouldn't)) or `$('@("#" + ViewBag.PropID)')...`

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will work:

```
<script>
var id = ViewBag.PropID.val(); // You may needed to work on this part 
var elem = $('#'+id);
if (elem) {
    $('html').scrollTop(elem.offset().top);
    $('html').scrollLeft(elem.offset().left);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tried but not working. Here is my Code. @foreach (var item in Model)
{<tr>
                                <td><span id="@ViewBag.PropID">@item.PropId</span></td>
                                <td>@item.OwnerName</td>} and here is the jQuery <script>
        var id = parseInt(@ViewBag.PropID); // You may needed to work on this part
        if (id != 0) {alert(id); }
        var elem = $('#' + id);
        alert(elem);
        if (elem) { $('html').scrollTop(elem.offset().top);        $('html').scrollLeft(elem.offset().left);$('') }
    </script>. Kindly help